# Word for person that transports something securely

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (or 2 maybe) that represents a person transporting something securely. I'm looking for something more interesting than "security guard". It shouldn't be tied to him being a driver for example. Please treat the images merely as examples.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [*Armored vehicle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armored_car_(valuables)) drivers?

Comment: Thanks but that's too long and too specific... It doesn't necessarily need to be a driver. The picture above is just as a guide ... I'll clarify the question.

Comment: How about **convoy**? But it also means that there will be more than one vehicle.

Comment: Exactly. It shouldn't need to involve vehicles. Imagine taking that guy and instead of having him deliver from building A to building B, having him deliver between floors of the same building.

Comment: Back about 30 years ago when I was sorta in the same room where this stuff was going on he was known simply as an *armed guard* (and "via armed guard" was stamped on the crate).

Comment: @HotLicks +1 that's what I thought, too. But the OP doesn't want that, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

**Armed Courier** (or Messenger, Escort or Guard)

Related article: [Armed Courier/Armed Escort](http://www.rsexecutiveprotection.com/executive-protection-services/armed-courierarmed-escort/)

> Our clients often have very valuable documents that must be delivered to their accountant,  lawyers, clients, or bank every day.   RS Executive Protection takes pride in ensuring the safe and secure arrival of your assets to its destination using RS Executive Protection **Armed Courier**.  Some of the courier services we can help with:
>
> - Payroll Deliveries
> - Armed Asset Escorts (Domestic & International)
> - Precious Metals & Stones (Pick up & delivery)

Related: Armed Forces Courier Service — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Armed+Forces+Courier+Service)

> A joint service of the Departments of the Army, the Navy, and the Air Force, with the Chief of Staff, US Army, as Executive Agent. The courier service provides one of the available methods for the secure and expeditious transmission of material requiring protected handling by **military courier**.

According to Wikipedia, most [**armored vehicles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armored_car_(valuables)) have [2 to 3 occupants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armored_car_(valuables)#Guards):

> - A **driver**, who is normally never allowed to leave the vehicle until it returns to the garage
> - One or two **guards** who deliver the cash or valuables
>
> Depending on the jurisdiction, the **guards are armed**. Most guards are issued shotguns, while some carry handguns, submachine guns or assault rifles. These guards are required to have training before they can carry them.
>
> Six member states of the European Union prohibit weapons during cash-in-transit (CIT) operations.
>
> Some are also required to wear bullet-proof vests and sometimes helmets.

Comment: As detailed in the question's comments section, this is way too specific. I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki Maybe just ["armed Federal Agents"](https://nnsa.energy.gov/aboutus/ourprograms/defenseprograms/securetransportation)

Comment: That is way too broad as agent can mean many things. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent

Comment: Well it's an A for effort but I don't think agreeing to something that isn't right just because of the effort involved is the way to go. Your latest edit (armed courier) is getting closer but it's still not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki It's alright. We're all here to learn something new everyday.

Comment: Well, I'm unconvinced that there *is* a better word than "courier" for this, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

***bonded courier***

> I am sending you forty ten-carat diamonds, all of them D-Flawless as you
>   specified, by **bonded courier**.

**courier**, [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/courier)

> a person or company that takes messages, letters, or parcels from one
>   person or place to another

**bonded**, [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bonded)

> Covered or guaranteed by a surety bond or a fidelity bond

**surety bond** [suretybonds.com](https://www.suretybonds.com/what-is-a-surety-bond.html)

> A surety bond is a contract between three parties—the principal (you),
>   the surety (us) and the obligee (the entity requiring the bond)—in
>   which the surety financially guarantees to an obligee that the
>   principal will act in accordance with the terms established by the
>   bond.

In the example I gave, if the courier is hijacked, or absconds with the diamonds, or is hit by a car and the diamonds fall into the sewer system, is it the surety who absorbs the loss.  See the link for details on how surety bonds work.

The security arrangements are not specified in this answer. They must satisfy the surety, but they don't have to be the armored car the OP pictured.